# info.plist - xmlstarlet does not return specified node

Tags: xml, macos, info.plist, xmlstarlet

I am attempting to parse an info.plist (for an iOS app) using xmlstartlet.  I'm doing this in OSX on a MacBook Pro.  Here is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My iOS App</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>local.nowhere.MyiOSApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.3.0</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>external-accessory</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>321</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <array>
        <string>Location enabled?</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>needs access to the camera</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>needs access to photos</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>needs access to the calendar</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>needs access to bluetooth</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my xmlstarlet command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/plist/dict[key='CFBundleVersion']" -v string ./Info.plist
```

Here is the output:

```
Attempt to load network entity http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd
9.3
My iOS App
local.nowhere.MyiOSApp
3.3.0
321
needs access to the camera
needs access to photos
needs access to the calendar
needs access to bluetooth
UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset
Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage
```

Any ideas why it's returning all 'string' nodes at that level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching `dict` and getting the value of `string` so it's returning all the strings in `dict`.

The check to see if there is a `key` element with the value `CFBundleVersion` doesn't do anything other than only select the `dict` if that's true.

Try selecting the `key` itself and then getting the value of the first following-sibling `string`...

```
xmlstarlet sel --net -t -m "/plist/dict/key[.='CFBundleVersion']" -v "following-sibling::string[1]" ./Info.plist
```

This will return:

```
321
```

Comment: Hmmm... not much help there. That returns:  

`Attempt to load network entity http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd`

Comment: @PaulM - Oh yes sorry. That's because your system identifier in your doctype declaration is pointing to a url. Try adding `--net` after `sel` in the command line (see updated answer). I didn't have this issue because I didn't copy the doctype declaration when testing. I added the doctype, reproduced the error, and then verified the error was resolved by adding `--net`.

Answer (score 1):

Or for a quicker running version of above (because I can't comment on it), don't lookup the DTD & ignore STDERR:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/plist/dict/key[text()='CFBundleVersion']" -v "following-sibling::string[1]" ./Info.plist 2>/dev/null
```